# rails refactoring association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, model-associations

Hi I'm working on a legacy project where i need to refactor some old model association inorder to get useful data.

We have a User model

```
class User
 has_many :user_task
end

class Project
 has_many :task
end

class Task
 belongs_to :project
 has_many :user_task
end

class UserTask
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :task
end
```

I want to get the project name and number of tasks a user is working on that project user working on.

I gave a try using `has_many :through` but still didn’t get what i expected.

Could someone give me a hint on this ?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to structure your associations as following:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :user_tasks # should be plural
 has_many :tasks, through: :user_tasks
 has_many :projects, through: :user_tasks
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :tasks # should be plural
end

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :project # `tasks` table should have project_id
 has_many :user_tasks # should be plural
end

class UserTask < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :task
 has_one :project, through: :task
end
```

Some sample commands snippet:

```
:022 > User.create(name: 'kiddorails')
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (2.4ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("name", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["name", "kiddorails"], ["created_at", "2018-05-25 12:22:21.079472"], ["updated_at", "2018-05-25 12:22:21.079472"]]
   (0.7ms)  commit transaction
 => #<User id: 1, name: "kiddorails", created_at: "2018-05-25 12:22:21", updated_at: "2018-05-25 12:22:21">

 :023 > Project.create name: 'production'
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (1.2ms)  INSERT INTO "projects" ("name", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["name", "production"], ["created_at", "2018-05-25 12:22:37.653901"], ["updated_at", "2018-05-25 12:22:37.653901"]]
   (0.6ms)  commit transaction
 => #<Project id: 1, name: "production", created_at: "2018-05-25 12:22:37", updated_at: "2018-05-25 12:22:37">

 :024 > Project.create name: 'staging'
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "projects" ("name", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["name", "staging"], ["created_at", "2018-05-25 12:22:40.349378"], ["updated_at", "2018-05-25 12:22:40.349378"]]
   (2.4ms)  commit transaction
 => #<Project id: 2, name: "staging", created_at: "2018-05-25 12:22:40", updated_at: "2018-05-25 12:22:40">

 :025 > Task.create name: 'orchestration', project_id: 1
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  Project Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "projects".* FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "tasks" ("project_id", "name", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["project_id", 1], ["name", "orchestration"], ["created_at", "2018-05-25 12:22:55.606865"], ["updated_at", "2018-05-25 12:22:55.606865"]]
   (1.0ms)  commit transaction
 => #<Task id: 1, project_id: 1, name: "orchestration", created_at: "2018-05-25 12:22:55", updated_at: "2018-05-25 12:22:55">

 :026 > Task.create name: 'deploy', project_id: 2
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  Project Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "projects".* FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  SQL (1.2ms)  INSERT INTO "tasks" ("project_id", "name", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["project_id", 2], ["name", "deploy"], ["created_at", "2018-05-25 12:23:00.446630"], ["updated_at", "2018-05-25 12:23:00.446630"]]
   (2.5ms)  commit transaction
 => #<Task id: 2, project_id: 2, name: "deploy", created_at: "2018-05-25 12:23:00", updated_at: "2018-05-25 12:23:00">

 :027 > Project.first.tasks
  Project Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "projects".* FROM "projects" ORDER BY "projects"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  Task Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "tasks".* FROM "tasks" WHERE "tasks"."project_id" = ?  [["project_id", 1]]
 => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Task id: 1, project_id: 1, name: "orchestration", created_at: "2018-05-25 12:22:55", updated_at: "2018-05-25 12:22:55">]>

 :028 > User.first.tasks
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  Task Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "tasks".* FROM "tasks" INNER JOIN "user_tasks" ON "tasks"."id" = "user_tasks"."task_id" WHERE "user_tasks"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 1]]
 => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>

 :029 > UserTask.create user_id: 1, task_id: 1
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Task Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "tasks".* FROM "tasks" WHERE "tasks"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "user_tasks" ("user_id", "task_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["user_id", 1], ["task_id", 1], ["created_at", "2018-05-25 12:23:19.931540"], ["updated_at", "2018-05-25 12:23:19.931540"]]
   (2.2ms)  commit transaction
 => #<UserTask id: 1, user_id: 1, task_id: 1, created_at: "2018-05-25 12:23:19", updated_at: "2018-05-25 12:23:19">

 :030 > User.first.tasks
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  Task Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "tasks".* FROM "tasks" INNER JOIN "user_tasks" ON "tasks"."id" = "user_tasks"."task_id" WHERE "user_tasks"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 1]]
 => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Task id: 1, project_id: 1, name: "orchestration", created_at: "2018-05-25 12:22:55", updated_at: "2018-05-25 12:22:55">]>

 :031 > User.first.projects
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  Project Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects" INNER JOIN "tasks" ON "projects"."id" = "tasks"."project_id" INNER JOIN "user_tasks" ON "tasks"."id" = "user_tasks"."task_id" WHERE "user_tasks"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 1]]
 => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Project id: 1, name: "production", created_at: "2018-05-25 12:22:37", updated_at: "2018-05-25 12:22:37">]>

 :032 > UserTask.first.project
  UserTask Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "user_tasks".* FROM "user_tasks" ORDER BY "user_tasks"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  Project Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "projects".* FROM "projects" INNER JOIN "tasks" ON "projects"."id" = "tasks"."project_id" WHERE "tasks"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
 => #<Project id: 1, name: "production", created_at: "2018-05-25 12:22:37", updated_at: "2018-05-25 12:22:37">
```

Comment: good answer - though I don't feel the queries are important information here. Without them, it would make the commands a lot easier to read

Comment: @TheCha͢mp I personally find that the presence of queries while explaining any such answer gives more idea about what's happening behind the scenes. It is essential to save people from saying that rails does 'some magic' :)